# The if statements are not running in this medium finding code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1, num2, num3;
        System.out.println("Enter first number.");
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number.");
        num2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter third number.");
        num3 = scan.nextInt();

        if(num1 > num2 && num2 > num3) {
            System.out.println("Medium value is: " + num2);
        } else if (num3 > num1 && num1 > num2) {
            System.out.println("Medium value is: " + num1);
        } else if (num1 > num3 && num3 > num2) {
            System.out.println("Medium value is: " +num3);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to find the medium number from the entered numbers, but the if statements are not running.

Comment: I've not run your code, but I don't see any obvious problems on first glance. Have you run it using your IDE's debugger? If not do this, stepping through the code to see what happens at each line.

Comment: What sample data are you providing the application?

Comment: Your if statements are not comprehensive. What if num3 is the greatest and num 1 is the least? num2 should be median, but your if blocks will not catch this. Same for the other values. Best to run through your code logically on paper.

Comment: You need to simplify your if statements

Comment: Logic looks off. Your first condition should yield `num3` as the medium. You can do this easier with a little math. `total = a + b + c;` then find the `min` and `max`. The `middle = total - min - max;`

Comment: add an else with a `println` in it. If only to know that none of your conditions have been met. Also you might make your life easier by storing your values in an ArrayList, sorting it and picking the middle value from the list.

Comment: And what happens if two numbers are the same, or all three are the same?

Comment: @PaulRooney I think your comment is good enough to be an answer; it makes both the points I think need making. It's not even necessary to provide a complete example as I think this is an assignment -- first version of the question especially looks so (apologies to author if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but why not get rid of the `if` statements completely and try something like:

```java
return Math.max(Math.max(Math.min(num1, num2), Math.min(num2, num3)), Math.min(num1, num3));

// [0, 10, 10] -> 10
// [50, 30, 20] -> 30
// [1, 1, 1] -> 1
// etc.
```

This will also handle the cases where the numbers are equal, or two of the three are equal.